# Firebase security rules like this?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a collection, lets say it is called **rooms**.
In the rooms i have its **name, its hashed password, "members", subcollections**, which looks something like this:

```
rooms: {
  room1Uid: {
    name: "room name",
    password: "hashed password",
    members: {
      member1Uid: { joindate: "timestamp"},
      member2Uid: { joindate: "timestamp"},
      ...
    },
    resource1: {
      something: "...",
    },
    resource2: {
      something: "...",
    }
  },

  room2Uid: {...}
}
```

I wish that only users authenticated can read and write anything under the roomUid which are contained in the members list.

So, for example **request.auth.uid == member1Uid** can read **resource1** from under room1Uid.

Comment: is it realtime database?

Comment: it is **firestore**

Comment: What kind of authentication method you are using? (Email and password, anonymous ... )

Comment: signInWithEmailAndPassword() for user authentication. But i would like to filter the user who can access the resources that a room has.

Comment: Please check the answer

Comment: Thank you for answering. I wont be able to check it for few days. But i will come back when i did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents), A sample code given below

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /rooms/room1Uid/{document=**} {

      allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/rooms/room1Uid/members/$(request.auth.uid))

    }
  }
}
```

Try this and let me know, it is working or not